# Can someone recommend an orthonormal system with respect to Gaussian measure

Tags: combinatorics, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, measure-theory, numerical-methods

Can someone recommend an orthonormal system in (better to be in $C^2(\mathbb{R})\cap L^2(\mathbb{R})$) with respect to Gaussian measure $dm=e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx$
whose derivative is also orthonormal (or take on finite values)? (or only derivative is orthonormal)

One may first think of Hermite Polynomial at recognize its fails to be orthonormal.

Comment: If $\{ f_n \}$ is orthonormal with respect to $dm$, and if $\{ f_n' \}$ is also orthonormal, then $\frac{d}{dx}$ would be unitary, which it is not.

Comment: A standard orthonormal system for the Gaussian measure is the Hermite system ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials so I guess examine its derivatives.  Note there are two different standard ways to normalize these, so you get two chances to find one that works for you!  Formulas for derivatives are on that page.